# img inside d-flex div causes image to overflow in Bootstrap 4 in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a page with bootstrap 4 grid system, it renders fine on all browsers except IE 11. I have this [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/36238/) on jsfiddle that you can view in IE 11 to see that the image gets stretched inside a d-flex container. How can I fix this?

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row py-3 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3 bg-primary">
      This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-center">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bg-primary">
      This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grid system allows 12 columns across the page so try this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row py-3 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3 bg-primary">
      This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center">
      <img style=height:100%;width: 100%; src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bg-primary">
      This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image This content is longer than image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `justify-content-center` won't have any meaning then, and I purposely left a column for spacing

Comment: i cant understand you want the image to be equally spaced or ? can u provide more information about what u want  to do

Comment: have you tested this on IE 11? it runs fine on IE 10 but in 11 it causes the image to stretch and if you see in any other browser you'll see that the image is not only vertically centred but contained not stretched. I want the same effect in IE11

Comment: <img style=height:100%;width:100%; src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg"> how about adding this

Comment: I'll check but it would be better if I don't have to do inline!

Comment: `width: 100%` does the trick and I set `height` to `auto`. Thanks